# Conversion of CString to std::string without 'GetString()'

Tags: c++, type-conversion, cstring, stdstring

if m_attr.GetValue() returns a CString then:

why does the below code work without error message ... only warning message 'C4927'?

```
std::string sigCncDialog::GetSignalAttributeValue()
{return m_attr.GetValue();}
```

the correct would be of course:

```
std::string sigCncDialog::GetSignalAttributeValue()
{return m_attr.GetValue().GetString();}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of two evils:

- `CString` has a [conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569(v=vs.60).aspx) allowing implicit conversion to a C-style character pointer
- the compiler apparently allows an implicit conversion sequence to contain two user-defined conversions, `CString -> const char* -> std::string`, with just the [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/727wstex.aspx) you mention, even though such a conversion is forbidden by standard C++